# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. --> contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to make an nft contract with royalties that would work for me. And I don't really understand solidity. I am going to deploy the contract in REMIX IDE solidity compiler.
If there are developers for whom it is easy and who understand, then I would be glad if you could help.

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> contract.sol:30:9:
   |
30 |         _setTokenRoyalty(tokenId, royaltFeeReceiver, fee);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you can, please help me to fix the error to deploy the contract.
Here is my code with error:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/common/ERC2981.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    function mintWithRoyalty(address recipient, string memory uri, address royaltFeeReceiver, uint96 fee) public returns(uint256){
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(recipient, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
        _setTokenRoyalty(tokenId, royaltFeeReceiver, fee);

        return tokenId;
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, uint256 batchSize)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId, batchSize);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```